# spring boot logs strange square brackets

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I've been seeing weird square brackets and can't find and info on what there might be,
logs looking like that:

```
--2022-08-23 08:47:44.882  INFO [,,,] 30446 --- [)-192.168.0.165] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
--2022-08-23 08:47:44.882  INFO [,,,] 30446 --- [)-192.168.0.165] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
--2022-08-23 08:47:44.922  INFO [,,,] 30446 --- [)-192.168.0.165] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 40 ms
```

as you can see there are brackets with commas after log level, at some point info in the brackets change like this:

```
DEBUG [,080578da-b973-450b-9cae-2c5900ab56fe,080578da-b973-450b-9cae-2c5900ab56fe,]
```

can't really find what that could be, i'am using default spring boot logging pattern,
could it be wrongfully used MDC without redeclaring the logging pattern?
if it is MDC problem then why any value in the brackets look like this: `080578da-b973-450b-9cae-2c5900ab56fe`

The logger I'm using is Slf4j

Comment: Are you using `spring-cloud-sleuth`? Can you show us a list of dependencies you use?

Comment: @g00glen00b added dependency list to the question

Comment: @g00glen00b so It actually seems like 'spring-cloud-sleuth' is the tool that provides data in the brackets, first time encountering it, dont really get yet what that data in the brackets means but it doesn't really matter now, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Indeed, this library adds extra information to the logs to track logs across microservices. I added an answer explaining the meaning and how you could solve it (by removing the library) for the people of the future stumbling across the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if you use [Spring Cloud Sleuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth). Spring Cloud Sleuth is a framework that adds the following to your logs:

- The application name (from the `spring.application.name` property)
- A trace ID (a unique ID for each user-initiated request)
- A span ID (a unique ID for a unit of work)

These IDs can be used to correlate log messages in a distributed system (eg. microservices), because these IDs will be passed from microservice to microservice. In [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-first-application-run) you can find an example of what this looks like.

In your case, you're not using these properties, which is why they're empty. The trace ID is automatically generated upon each request, which is why you sometimes see `[,,]` and `[,XXX,]`.
If you're not interested in these trace/span IDs, you can remove the `spring-cloud-sleuth` or `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` library.